# Understanding PHP Documentation Code

Tags: php, mysqli

I was reading [this documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) today and got confused when seeing the output.

The lines of code:

```
/* numeric array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);

/* associative array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);

/* associative and numeric array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row["CountryCode"]);
```

Produces the result:

```
Kabul (AFG)
Qandahar (AFG)
Herat (AFG)
```

If there's a combination of loop and `data_seek()`, then I can understand why the output is different each time. Shouldn't the output from the code above like this?

```
Kabul (AFG)
Kabul (AFG)
Kabul (AFG)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think, the array cursor will move forward each time you fetch the same result set. The very reason you loop to fetch all the rows in the result set. Unless you are using something like `fetchAll` for PDO, not sure for mysqli.

Comment: the recordset cursor is being advanced with each call to `fetch_array` with various params so this is how it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just had to investigate a little further. The page says that this function "is an extended version of the mysqli_fetch_row()", while by following the link, you'd learn that "Each subsequent call to this function will return the next row within the result set"